# "translation rate" or "translational rate"?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, attributive-nouns

When expressing the meaning "**rate** at which the mRNA is **translated** to proteins by ribosomes", should I use "**translational rate**" or "**translation rate**"? And similarly, when describing efficiency of this process, should I used "**translational efficiency**" or "**translation efficiency**"?

I read that noun can be used as adjectives. When searching usage at website of a famous bioligical journal, both usage can be found:

https://www.nature.com/search?order=relevance&q=%22translational%20efficiency%22

https://www.nature.com/search?order=relevance&q=%22translation%20efficiency%22

Is there a correct one and the other is incorrect or both ones are acceptable?

Comment: It seems like a knowledge of the particular terminology of the domain is needed. But in standard English I would prefer translation rate.

Comment: Yes. The attributive noun ("translation rate") is to be preferred here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I also think  using noun is better with a meaning of "rate of translation" while the "translational rate" sounds more like "a special rate for something".

Comment: **rate of translation** is an idiomatic possibility. https://books.google.com/books?id=zM5qCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&dq=%22rate+of+translation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhn8z02urUAhWG2D4KHacQCmAQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22rate%20of%20translation%22&f=false

Comment: I think "translation rate" is the approved biological term, see for example [Maximizing Protein Translation Rate in the Ribosome Flow Model: The Homogeneous Case.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26357054)

Answer (score 1):

As with any *jargon* used in a specific academic or technical field, in any language, the answer is to use what your readers expect.  In this case it seems both *translation* and *translational* are used, and it's difficult to say if there is *any* difference in meaning between the two.  Examples:

> [Maximizing Protein Translation Rate in the Ribosome Flow Model: The Homogeneous Case.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26357054)
>
> [The synthesis rate of a protein in general is proportional to the concentration and translational efficiency of its mRNA.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3504442/)

It sounds as if these terms are interchangeable, but your best bet is to ask someone, such as a university professor, who is familiar with the literature.